# Libgdx picky about rendering polygon shapes

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, polygons

I may just be doing something wrong as I'm not really familiar with Libgdx yet.

What I'm trying to do is display multiple hexagons (preferably in a grid after I figure out how to even draw them properly). In the code below I'm trying to draw four hexagons next to one another with different but close y values. As you can see, only 2 out of 4 hexagons get drawn. What can I do to fix this?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMKo6.png

## Hex#draw method

```
public void draw(PolygonSpriteBatch batch) {
    // System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
    // some of the code was copied from another SO thread but I'm pretty sure I understand it
    // Creating the color filling (but textures would work the same way)
    Pixmap pix = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pix.setColor(0xDEADBEFF); // DE is red, AD is green and BE is blue.
    pix.fill();
    textureSolid = new Texture(pix);
    PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(textureSolid),
            new float[] {               // Four vertices
                    0, 0,               // Vertex 0        /2--4
                    30, -ROOT/2,        // Vertex 1       / |\ | \
                    30, ROOT/2,         // Vertex 2      0\ | \| /5
                    90, -ROOT/2,        // Vertex 3        \1--3/
                    90, ROOT/2,         // Vertex 4
                    120, 0
            }, new short[] {
            0, 1, 2,          // Two triangles using vertex indices.
            1, 3, 2,          // Take care of the counter-clockwise direction.
            3, 4, 2,
            3, 5, 4
    });
    poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
    poly.setOrigin(0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.draw(polyReg, x, y + ROOT/2);
}
```

## Main class

```
public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch;
    private static Set<Hex> renderables = new HashSet<Hex>();

    @Override
    public void create() {
        polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
        //new HexGrid(5, 2).generate();
        renderables.add(new Hex(0, 0));
        renderables.add(new Hex(120, 120));
        renderables.add(new Hex(240, 60));
        renderables.add(new Hex(360, -50));
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        polyBatch.begin();
        for (Hex hex : renderables) {
            hex.draw(polyBatch);
        }
        polyBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        polyBatch.dispose();
    }

    public static void addRenderable(Hex hex) {
        renderables.add(hex);
    }
}
```

If there's anything more I should add that you need then go ahead and ask. As I said, I'm new to Libgdx but it seems really good and I'm willing to learn about it.

edit: I hope I'm not violating the rules right now but bumppity bump bump.

Comment: You have a lot of stuff in the draw() that should not be there. Creating objects with native resources and not disposing them is fairly bad, Pixmap and Texture. Creating the sprites each time you draw them is somewhat suboptimal. Clearing the screen each time they are drawn probably doesnt help either. Draw some rectangles of expected size and position with shape renderer. Use viewports.